# confused as to why same methods in js function have different results

Tags: javascript

very confused as to why this works:

```
cPassword.style.borderColor = matchCol;
```

but this does not:

```
submitButton.style.backgroundColor = #a2bb33;
```

cPassword is defined here:

```
<input type="password" name="cPassword" class="iBox"  id="cPassword" onkeyup="passwordValidation()" placeholder="confirm it!" autocomplete="off">
```

submit button is defined here:

```
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="submit" disabled="disabled" onmouseout="SubmitToolTipHide()" onmouseover="SubmitToolTip()">
```

unless im being stupid, they are defined in the same way and therefore the above code should work. but it doesn't. in fact it disables angularjs working altogether for some bizarre reason

Comment: `#a2bb33` is not valid JavaScript syntax. You have to assign a **string**: `"#a2bb33"`.

Comment: @FelixKling brill. you should have put this is as answer so i could reward thee (and help my own rep!). but thanks man

Answer (score 1):

`#a2bb33` is not valid JavaScript syntax. You have to put the color value inside a string

```
submitButton.style.backgroundColor = "#a2bb33";
```

Your first example works because `matchCol` can correctly be parsed as *identifier* (variable). Of course this variable also has to exist.